# Getting location of cell in JXTreeTable

Tags: java, swing, swingx

How to determine the location of a particular cell in JXTreeTable on screen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

not sure, but merging some information gathered on topic.

- this link shows the way to compute swing component coordinates: [Getting coordinates of a component in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269540/getting-coordinates-of-a-component-in-java)
- this [link](https://pirlwww.lpl.arizona.edu/resources/guide/software/SwingX/org/jdesktop/swingx/JXTreeTable.html) shows, that `JXTreeTable` extends `JTable`:- this link shows the way to retrieve coordinates of cell in `JTable`: http://www.java-forums.org/awt-swing/23061-jtable-cell-coordinates.html

So final solution could theoretically just calling method (from `JTable API`):

```
public Rectangle getCellRect(int row, int column, boolean includeSpacing)
```

And if needed then using `SwingUtilities.convertRectangle` get the exact screen placement.

Honestly, I'd be quite curious if it works if you give it a try :)