# Simulate JDialog Drag and Drop in JFC

Tags: java, awt

I wish to simulate a drag and drop of JDialog from one location to another location on a JXTreeTable in my JFC.

```
TestHelper().enterDragAndLeave(
    new MouseEventData(this, myDialog.getRootPane()),
    new MouseEventData(this, treeTable),
    1
);
```

However, this is not working for me. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I would give a try to:

```
java.awt.Robot
```

as Javadocs describes it (on http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html):
"This class is used to generate native system input events for the purposes of test automation, self-running demos, and other applications where control of the mouse and keyboard is needed. The primary purpose of Robot is to facilitate automated testing of Java platform implementations."

Follwing sequence should work:

```
mouseMove(int x, int y) 
mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK) 
mouseMove(int x, int y) 
mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK)
```

If you're unsure about getting the coordinates of particular target location, and if it would be a cell in `JXTreeTable`, my answer from yesterday should help: [Getting location of cell in JXTreeTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12097619/getting-location-of-cell-in-jxtreetable/12097951#12097951)